# How can I set VertxOptions for use in every Verticle?

Tags: vert.x

**Does Vertx have a simple way of setting options that will be used when creating all verticles?**

When debugging Vertx in an interactive debugger, you need to set some options to prevent the Vertx watchdog code (e.g., BlockedThreadChecker) from throwing exceptions.

The problem is I'm not sure how to set Vertx options so they will be used by all of the Vertx instances returned from the Vertx.vertx() factory method.

For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    VertxOptions vertxOptions = new VertxOptions();
    vertxOptions.setBlockedThreadCheckInterval(999888777666L);
    vertxOptions.setMaxEventLoopTime(999888777666L);
    Vertx myVertx = Vertx.vertx(vertxOptions);          // (A)
    Verticle myVerticle = new MyVerticle();             // (B)
    myVertx.depoyVerticle(myVerticle);                  // (C)

    App myApp = new App();
    myApp.run();
}

public void run(){
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();                        // (D)
    vertx.deployVerticle(new AnotherVerticle());
}

Some other code 
class AnotherVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    public void someOtherCode(){
        Verticle myVerticle = new MyVerticle();         // (E)
        vertx.deployVerticle(myVerticle);               // (F)
    }
 }
```

Step (A) creates a Vertx instance with options set.  Through trial and error when this instance is used to deploy verticles then Vertx BlockedThreadChecker doesn't complain.

In Step (B), a new Vertx instance is created when the AbstractVerticle how can I have the options set in Step (A)?

Furthermore, in other classes that have implement Verticles (Such as (E) and (F), how can those Vertx instances be created with the same options used in step (A).

Without doing this correctly, I see receive stack trace messages like

```
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 5853 ms, time limit is 2000
    io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create new `VertxOptions` instances from a single `JsonObject`.

But why do you need all those Vert.x instances in the first place? In most cases there should be a single Vert.x instance per process.

Comment: I don't necessarily want more than one Vertx instance, but if I have multiple classes that extend the AbstractVerticle, then each one gets is own unique Vertx instance.  A co-worker suggested I listen for configuration changes then apply the config changes to every Vertx instance.  I haven't looked at to do this yet.

Comment: This is not true. If you deploy all your verticles with a single Vert.x instance, there is no other instance created.

Comment: I wasn't using deploy vertical, just creating them with new MyClass (which extends AbstractVerticle).  I see the error in my ways and what you say makes perfect sense!  Light bulb moment.  Thanks